# How to centralize images and equations inside tables? vertically and horizontally

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I have this code of this table:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
    \normalsize
    \caption{Anything.}
    \label{tab:anm_estampas}
    \begin{center}
        %\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
        \begin{tabular}{l | c | l | c }
            \hline Text1 & Text2 & Text3 & Text4  \\\hline
            Resistor                    &   \figresistor        &    \estamparesistor           &   \eqresistor             \\
            Fonte de Corrente           &   \figfontecorrentecc &    \estampafontecorrentecc    &   \eqfontecorrentecc      
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \fonte{Figuras do Autor}
\end{table}
```

[image]

The commands inside the cells are just macros to put images and equations:

```
\newcommand{\figresistor}{%
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{estampa_simbolo_resistor.eps}
}

\newcommand{\figfontecorrentecc}{%
    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{estampa_simbolo_fontecorrentecc.eps}
}

\newcommand{\estamparesistor}{%
    \includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{estampa_matriz_resistor.eps}
}

\newcommand{\estampafontecorrentecc}{%
    \includegraphics[width=1.2cm]{estampa_matriz_fontecorrentecc.eps}
}

\newcommand{\eqresistor}{%
  \ensuremath{%
        \begin{aligned}
            I_j = G(V_j-V_{j'})  \\
            I_{j'} = -G(V_j-V_{j'})
        \end{aligned}       
  }%
}

\newcommand{\eqfontecorrentecc}{%
  \ensuremath{%
        \begin{aligned}
            I_j = J  \\
            I_{j'} = -J
        \end{aligned}       
  }%
}
```

I've tried many things like \centering inside each cell but nothing worked.

How can I centralize everything cell content horizontally and vertically? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please complete from your code fragments one, complete small document which reproduce your problem. In images try to define baseline.  This may help you.

Comment: I won't post this as an answer, since I can't work with most of the code.
Have you tried to insert the content of the cells inside a 1×1 tabular environment? Might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horizontal alignment obviously can be obtained by using `c` in the column specification rather than `l`.

For vertical alignment, use

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
```

in the preamble, and use

```
\includegraphics[valign=c,width=2cm]{example-image}
```

for the images. The equations should then be vertically centered automatically.

I had to use generic images as I don't have yours.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- you should provide MWE
- without it answer is not complete
- I would not include math as images
- by use of `tabularray` package, a possible way to solve your problem is:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\newcommand\figresistor{\includegraphics[width=5em,valign=m]{example-image-duck}}
\newcommand\estamparesistor{\includegraphics[width=5em,valign=m]{example-image-duck}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!h]
\caption{Anything.}
\label{tab:anm_estampas}
\centering
    \begin{tblr}{hline{1,2}=solid, vlines,
                 colspec={Q[l,m] Q[c] Q[c] Q[c,mode=math]},
                 row{1}={font=\bfseries, mode=text, c},
                 rowsep=5pt
                 }
Text 1      & Text 2    & Text 3    & Text 4                \\
Resistor    & \figresistor        
                        & \estamparesistor
                                    & \begin{aligned}
                                        I_j & G(V_j-V_j')   \\
                                        I_j'& - G(V_j-V_j')
                                      \end{aligned}         \\
Fonte de Corrente           
            & \figresistor
                        & \estamparesistor
                                    & \begin{aligned}
                                        I_j & J   \\
                                        I_j'& - J
                                      \end{aligned}         \\
    \end{tblr}
\caption{Figuras do Autor}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]